# Error: Module did not self register for node js function called through amazon lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, aws-lambda

Error: Module did not self-register.

I am using xml2json module to convert json data to xml.
The API is running fine in my local console.
But it is not working fine with amazon lambda function.

It gives an error of module did not self register.

Comment: Since AWS Lambda require all the dependencies in the deployed code, have you zipped your node_modules directory or build your code with a bundler like webpack?